# How to echo db value in php edit form option

Tags: php, html, mysql

I currently have an edit form, where all values are echoed from the db as the "values" for each input, the user would then retype and "save" the value to append to the db. All echoes work but i have been unable to echo the database value for the options... anybody knows how to?

& Thanks

Code below:

```
<fieldset>
    <form id="input-form" method="POST" action="../php/edit-import-record.php">
        Airway Bill Number*:
        <input type=text name=AwbNo size=30 class="input" value="<?php echo $awb ?>" required>
        Client Code:
        <?php               //OPEN DROP DOWN BOX
            include("../login/dbinfo.inc.php");
            $comm=@mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
            $rs=@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 
            $sql=   "SELECT DISTINCT ClientCode, ClientName FROM tbl_client ORDER BY ClientCode";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            echo "<select name='ClientCode'>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option  value='" . $row['ClientCode'] ."'>" . $row['ClientName'] ."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select><br>";   //CLOSE DROP DOWN BOX   
        ?><br>
        Vessel Name*:
        <input type=text name=VesselName class=form-control id=inputSuccess size=30 class="input" value="<?php echo $vsl ?>" required>
        Number of Pieces:
        <input type=number name=Pieces size=30 class="input" value="<?php echo $pcs ?>" >
        Total Weight (kg):
        <input type=number name=Weight size=30 class="input" value="<?php echo $wgt ?>" >
        Carrier:
        <input type=text name=Carrier size=30 class="input" value="<?php echo $car ?>" >    
        Sender:
        <input type=text name=Sender size=30 class="input" value="<?php echo $snd ?>" > 
        Status:
        <input type=text name=Status size=30 class="input" value="<?php echo $stt ?>" > 
        Arrival Date:
        <input type=date name=ArrivalDate size=30 class="input" value="<?php echo $ard ?>" >    
        Customs:
        <input type=text name=Customs size=30 class="input" value="<?php $ctm ?>" > 
        <br><small>Fields marked with * are required to be filled in.</small>
        <div class="inputformbutton">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Reset</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Create Record</button>  
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the error suppression operator (`@`) and see if you're getting DB errors. Also, `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` instead.

Comment: As already stated, look into mysqli, also you used the const localhost, not the string value "localhost" try fixing that. As @wogsland said, @ should not be used. Use or die(mysql_error()); instead.

Comment: $comm=mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Nope no DB error when i removed the suppression operator, all of the above code works perfectly fine. Just unsure as to how to echo and place as the default value of the option?